# Exclude Combo box items that held in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, combobox

I have a `combo box` that is attached to a `datasource`

```
cboPies.DataSource = GetPies(txtCustomer.Text)
cboPies.DisplayMember = "PIES_DESCN"
cboPies.ValueMember = "PIES_ID"
```

I also have a `datagridView` that has a list of selections that have selected from the `combo box`.

I am trying to remove the items for the `combo box` if they have already have the item on the `Datagridview` or warn the user that it is already selected.

```
With dgvSelectedPies
    For indexDGV As Integer = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
        'cboSpecialty.Items.Remove(.Rows(indexDGV).Cells("PIES_DESCN").Value)
        cboSpecialty.Items.Remove(.Rows(indexDGV).Cells("PIES_ID").Value)

    Next
End With
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message when you run the code?

Comment: No it does not show an error but it does not appear to remove any items that are already in the datagridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a data source then you should not be interacting with the `Items` collection.  [The MSDN documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A data source can be a database, a Web service, or an object that can
>   later be used to generate data-bound controls. When the DataSource
>   property is set, **the items collection cannot be modified**.

Instead, you should be managing your own collection using a [BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx).

Example in C# (sorry):

```
protected BindingList<Pies> ComboDataSource { get; set; }
```

...

```
ComboDataSource = new BindingList<Pies>(GetPies(txtCustomer.Text));
cboPies.DataSource = ComboDataSource;
cboPies.DisplayMember = "PIES_DESCN"
cboPies.ValueMember = "PIES_ID"
```

...

```
if(ComboDataSource.Contains(pieInDataGrid))
{
    ComboDataSource.Remove(pieInDataGrid);
}
```